# HTTP POST PARAMETERS ENCODING ERROR ANDROID

Tags: php, android, http-post, androidhttpclient

I am developing an Android App.
I need to connect to my PHP and i am usig HttpPost. This is my code. I've followed  several tutorials and it doesn't work.
The error is that the PHP doesn't receive the parameters that I pass from my App code. Although it connects correctly to the PHP.
I've used POSTman to find errors in the PHP but it works fine.
I put my code here :

```
private void httppostconnect(ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametros, String urlwebserver) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlwebserver);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametros));
        //ejecuto peticion enviando datos por POST
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("GetBuscadas", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what those parameters are, your "parametros" var.
The usual problem would be not sending content type headers.

Comment: parametros contains two String namevaluepairs. Is that what you are asking?